# When i add new input field for phone to my form , i need it to show Phone 2 ..Phone 3 etc

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form , in which there is a Phone 1 input filed. When i click "Add Phone " button i need it to display new input field that says Phone 2 ...Phone 3 , etc. I got it to work  with showing Phone 2 only , every time when the button is clicked , but my approach is not the correct one , as i believe i need to have an IF statement , so that it can change the number phone - 2,3,4,5.

```js
function newPhone () {
   var phone = document.querySelector('.phone'); 
   var label = document.createElement('label') ;
   var input = document.createElement('input')
   var span = document.createElement('span')
   span.textContent= 'Phone 2';
   input.setAttribute('type','text')
   input.setAttribute('name', 'phones')
   label.appendChild(span);
   phone.appendChild(label);
   phone.appendChild(input)
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <div class="field">
     <label>First name</label><input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
     <label>Last name</label><input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
     <strong>Phones</strong>
     <div id="list-phones">
       <div class="phone">
        <label>Phone <span>1</span></label><input name="phones[]" 
         type="text">
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="add_phone" type="button" onclick="newPhone()">Add 
  phone</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a variable to keep track of number. i.e. `i` here.

```js
var i = 1;

function newPhone () {
  i++;
  var phone = document.querySelector('.phone'); 
  var label = document.createElement('label') ;
  var input = document.createElement('input')
  var span = document.createElement('span')
  span.textContent= 'Phone '+i;
  input.setAttribute('type','text')
  input.setAttribute('name', 'phones-'+i)
  label.appendChild(span);
  phone.appendChild(label);
  phone.appendChild(input)
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <div class="field">
     <label>First name</label><input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
     <label>Last name</label><input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
     <strong>Phones</strong>
     <div id="list-phones">
       <div class="phone">
        <label>Phone <span>1</span></label><input name="phones-1" 
         type="text">
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="add_phone" type="button" onclick="newPhone()">Add 
  phone</button>
</form>
```